# Programming with FTDI ft311 development board

Tags: java, android, crash, i2c, ftdi

I'm currently writing an Android app that'll interface with an MCU that'll use an FTDI chip for I2C communication. Currently I have the FTDI ft311 Dev Board and trying to test out the sample applications provided by FTDI. I am working with the [I2CDemo app](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/Android_Projects.htm). I have the board hooked up to a TI MSP-EXP430FR2433 eval board running a simple program generating ASCII values held in the buffer.

My problem now is that when I launch the I2CDemo application, I can only read from the buffer once and any subsequent request causes the app into an ANR error. Same goes for writing to the MCU. I can't seem to understand why this happens even from examining the code provided.

I pulled the log from the adb trace file and here's a part of it:

```
DALVIK THREADS (12):
"Thread-2" prio=5 tid=12 Runnable
| group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d46280 self=0x7fb1a05600
| sysTid=30669 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fa6a42450
| state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=5410 stm=0 core=4 HZ=100
| stack=0x7fa6940000-0x7fa6942000 stackSize=1037KB
| held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
at 
com.I2CDemo.FT311I2CInterface$handler_thread.run(FT311I2CInterface.java:458)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please try to find out where in your code the problem probably lies, or provide any logs/errors the app crash provides. You should provide an [mcve] so that the question can more easily be reproduced and answered

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated the question and also got a reply from FTDI:

_The FT311 project is developed at the period of android OS 4.x. I think the problem is that the access action(read/write) is placed in the main thread, and it will get some problems in the newer OS version. The customer could modify I2CDemoActivity.java and put the access action(read/write) in the new threads._